# routing issue, rails generates wrong url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

First of all, Happy Thanksgiving.

So my issue is with my routes, I'm not clear on why id param actually contains the entire object. Rails gives me this error:

```
user_url failed to generate from {:action=>"show", :controller=>"users", :id=>#<User id: 19, username: "Dr. Dorothy Buckridge", email: "kyra@hansenstehr.ca", crypted_password: nil, password_salt: nil, persistence_token: nil, created_at: "2009-11-10 19:38:31", updated_at: "2009-11-10 19:38:31", perishable_token: "", color: nil>}, expected: {:action=>"show", :controller=>"users"}, diff: {:id=>#<User id: 19, username: "Dr. Dorothy Buckridge", email: "kyra@hansenstehr.ca", crypted_password: nil, password_salt: nil, persistence_token: nil, created_at: "2009-11-10 19:38:31", updated_at: "2009-11-10 19:38:31", perishable_token: "", color: nil>}
```

The error occurs on this line:

```
<%= link_to recipe.user.username, recipe.user, :class => "user" %>
```

Any Idea? It seems like it should only be generating the `id` of the object for that attribute.

My controller in question is:

```
def index
  @recipes = Recipe.search params[:search], :field_weights => { :name => 20, :description => 10 }
end
```

Can't really see what the issue is.

Comment: Thanksgiving (whatever that means) is probably not programming related.

Comment: Real Thanksgiving was nearly 2 months ago. Get with the times.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you override to_params in the User model or any class that it inherits?

You can force the id with this:

```
 <%= link_to recipe.user.username, user_url(recipe.user.id), :class => "user" %>
```

Comment: Thanks EmFi.. Fixes the issue.

Answer (score 2):

This is a wild guess, but I had a similar issue when I typed `map.resource :user` instead of `map.resources :users` in the `routes.rb`

Otherwise validate against *EmFi*'s naswer.